# Why "come" and not "comes"?

Tags: american-english

This is the title of a Hallmark movie: A Wish Come True.

Unfortunately I can't speculate anything as why it is come and not comes.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe try asking in https://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's a past participle, like _a branch broken in two_.

Comment: Closely related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91028/wishes-coming-true-untrue

Answer (score 1):

The 'come' in 'A Wish Come True' is a
past participle.

Saying A Wish Come True
means a wish that
was or has been come true.

In other instances, we often omit articals and helping verbs when it comes writing titles of movies, posts or newsposts:

> - A website [was] created by.
> - A horse [was] fed by.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. All your comments and answers were helpful.